# Javascript valid form does not get submitted

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I am fairly new to javascript and fail to submit a valid form. I added the following code in my application to make a quick and easy client-side validation (text area is not empty)

```
function validate()
  {
     var textarea = document.getElementById('account_comments');
     if(textarea.value == "" )
     {
        alert( "Empty!" );
        return false;
     }
}
```

Javascript is called by rails in a view

```
<%= f.submit "Decline",:onclick=>"return(validate());" %>
```

The script works well and the window pops up when the text area is empty and does not pop up when the text area is filled. However, in both cases the form does not get submitted. I guess the reason is that I use the event "Onclick" instead of "Onsubmit".

However, when I swap Onclick by Onsubmit the form gets submitted even though the text area is empty.  What is the appropriate syntax to achieve this desired effect (when the text area is empty, I get a pop-up window and the form is not submitted, when the text area is filled, I do not get a pop-up window and the form gets submitted)? Thanks.

Comment: Why not add the "required" attribute to the textarea for validation directly? `<textarea required></textarea>` [here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/n1460b7y/)

Comment: If you are using `onclick` then you need to call `.submit()` explicitely if returned value is true else directly use `onsubmit`